# Firebase firestore offline support, save data at the start of app React Js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a book reading web app using React Js where the owner can make their own books and publish in the app . Since the data can be enormous so i wan't to ask is this possible or a good practice to load all the data at the start of web app, also i wan't to save it as a cache for offline support, what should i do for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Only load data you use

It's a simple principal, but only load data you use at that moment. You don't need book details on a book overview page (for example).

As for storing data and hydrating your state, this can be achieved quite easily with [redux-localstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-localstorage) if you're using the redux. I'm sure you can find another way to add data to local storage if not.

A tip, make sure you save only data you need in local storage and always check if its out of date before applying it to the app.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
  .onSnapshot({ includeMetadataChanges: true }, (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
          if (change.type === "added") {
              console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
          }

          var source = snapshot.metadata.fromCache ? "local cache" : "server";
          console.log("Data came from " + source);
      });
  });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline